# Why can't I do a hyphen in Django template view?

Tags: python, django, templates

```
{{profile.first-name.value}}
```

My variable is hypeh only...I wish I could do **first_name**, but many variables are hyphens.
However, due to this problem, I can't display my variables in the template. Why?

Comment: In what programming language is it true that "many variables are hyphens"? None that I can think of.

Comment: Lisp, CSS... I've run out now.

Comment: You can also access dictionary keys from a django template.  Slugs default to hyphens so if you have a dictionary of slugs and you are trying to access one it is impossible in a template...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The hyphen is an operator in Python. It would work better if you swapped all hyphens for underscores.

Comment: I think "would work better" should be "won't work at *all* unless".

Comment: How will we swap all hyphens with underscore in html template?

Answer (score -1):

OrderedDict dictionary types support hyphens:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects

This seems to be a side effect of the implementation of OrderedDict.  Notice below that the key value pairs are actually passed in as sets. I would bet that the implementation of OrderedDict doesn't use the "key" passed in the set as a true dict key thus getting around this issue.

Since this is a side-effect of the implementation of OrderedDict, it may not be something you want to rely on.  But it works.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

my_dict = OrderedDict([
    ('has-dash', 'has dash value'), 
    ('no dash', 'no dash value') 
])

print( 'has-dash: ' + my_dict['has-dash'] )
print( 'no dash: ' + my_dict['no dash'] )
```

Result:

```
has-dash: has dash value
no dash: no dash value
```