# How do I access dictionary keys that contain hyphens from within a Django template?

Tags: python, django

We have a system built on a custom database, where many of the attributes are named containing hyphens, ie:

```
user-name
phone-number
```

These properties cannot be accessed in templates as follows:

```
{{ user-name }}
```

Django throws an exception for this. I'd like to avoid having to convert all of the keys (and sub-table keys) to use underscores just to work around this. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A custom template tag is probably the only way to go here if you don't want to restructure your objects. For accessing dictionaries with an arbitrary string key, the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970244/django-templates-value-of-dictionary-key-with-a-space-in-it) provides a good example.

For the lazy:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def dictKeyLookup(the_dict, key):
   # Try to fetch from the dict, and if it's not found return an empty string.
   return the_dict.get(key, '')
```

Which you use like so:

```
{% dictKeyLookup your_dict_passed_into_context "phone-number" %}
```

If you want to access an object's attribute with an arbitrary string name, you could use the following:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def attributeLookup(the_object, attribute_name):
   # Try to fetch from the object, and if it's not found return None.
   return getattr(the_object, attribute_name, None)
```

Which you would use like:

```
{% attributeLookup your_object_passed_into_context "phone-number" %}
```

You could even come up with some sort of string seperator (like '__') for subattributes, but I'll leave that for homework :-)

Comment: I've used this solution, but changed it from a tag to a filter. It works well, thanks!

Comment: This definitely works, but how would you access a key that was inside a dict containing a dict as a value?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, I think you may be out of luck.  From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/):

> Variable names must consist of any letter (A-Z), any digit (0-9), an
>   underscore or a dot.

Comment: Right. I've also found a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213308/why-cant-i-do-a-hyphen-in-django-template-view

Answer (score -1):

OrderedDict dictionary types support dashes:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects

This seems to be a side effect of the implementation of OrderedDict.  Notice below that the key value pairs are actually passed in as sets. I would bet that the implementation of OrderedDict doesn't use the "key" passed in the set as a true dict key thus getting around this issue.

Since this is a side-effect of the implementation of OrderedDict, it may not be something you want to rely on.  But it works.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

my_dict = OrderedDict([
    ('has-dash', 'has dash value'), 
    ('no dash', 'no dash value') 
])

print( 'has-dash: ' + my_dict['has-dash'] )
print( 'no dash: ' + my_dict['no dash'] )
```

Result:

```
has-dash: has dash value
no dash: no dash value
```