# Iterate through JSON data in Django template

Tags: python, json, django, wagtail

I am having trouble iterating through some JSON data that I managed to import into my Django Wagtail project. I want to list travel advisories on a website that are pulled in from here: http://data.international.gc.ca/travel-voyage/index-updated.json

I was able to do this in my model like so:

```
import requests

def get_context(self, request):
    response = requests.get('http://data.international.gc.ca/travel-voyage/index-updated.json')
    json_response = response.json()

    data = json_response['data']

    context = super(TravelAdvisoriesPage, self).get_context(request)
    context['data'] = data

    return context
```

I am now unsure of how to get the data into my template. I am able to pull in all of the data using `{{ data }}`.

But how do I pull out specific items from that JSON data? I want to grab both the English and French name, url-slug, advisory-text, etc. And all of those are nested within `data > country code > language > item` within the JSON structure.

I have tried something like:

```
{% for country in data %}
  {{ data[country].eng.name }}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

This is giving me errors like `Could not parse the remainder: '[country].eng.name' from 'data[country].eng.name'`. How do you grab these in the template?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django templates have their own syntax different from Python syntax.  The brackets notation you're using in `{{ data[country].eng.name }}` isn't allowed.  Use the items dictionary function to iterate over both the dict key and the dict value:

```
{% for country_key, country_value in data.items %}
  {{ country_value.eng.name }}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you! This does pull in the name. It seems to be having an issue still with hyphenated items though. `friendly-date` does not work because it cannot parse the remainder '-date'.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's not an easy fix for that.  The best solution would probably be a [custom template tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252387/how-do-i-access-dictionary-keys-that-contain-hyphens-from-within-a-django-templa).