# Django `with` tag not recognizing keyword argument

Tags: python, django

I have the following code in my template:

```
{% include "entry_table/cell.html" with data_items = data_fields class="entry_table_title" only%}
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
"with" in 'include' tag needs at least one keyword argument.
```

I've tried replacing data_field (which is a variable I passed into the context) with a string, just in case that was what was causing the problem, but even if I make it:

```
{% include "entry_table/cell.html" with data_items = "unicorn" class="entry_table_title" only%}
```

I still get the same error. The only thing that fixes the issue is to get rid of data_items completely, as in:

```
{% include "entry_table/cell.html" with class="entry_table_title" only%}
```

So, what's the problem?

NOTE: I just realized that data_items is also a variable that is passed into the context of the page that is calling the other template, but when i changed the name to something else, it still didn't work. So that is not the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure, but try to remove spaces around `=`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Looks like Django is quite picky about whitespace in this instance. If I change...

```
{% include "entry_table/cell.html" with data_items = data_fields class="entry_table_title" only%}
```

...to...

```
{% include "entry_table/cell.html" with data_items=data_fields class="entry_table_title" only%}
```

...it works for me.

Comment: Works for me too. You'd think they'd put a note in the documentation or something.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem.  Only I was using dashes, which apparently aren't permitted in variable names.

I know this is an older question and it has already been sufficiently answered, but this is closely related, and comes up with a search, so for the sake of posterity ...

```
{% include "partials/forum-panel-header.html" with forum-name="demo name" forum-thread-count="22" forum-post-count="30" %}
```

It was necessary to change the dashes to underscores ...

```
{% include "partials/forum-panel-header.html" with forum_name="demo name" forum_thread_count="22" forum_post_count="30" %}
```

It would have been nice to know this before I wrote many variable names this way, and had to go back through all the nested files to fix them.

Of course I could have found the answer, had I looked, but at the time I didn't even realize I needed an answer.

Well, then I did find the answer (when I realized there was a problem), on [another post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213308/why-cant-i-do-a-hyphen-in-django-template-view), that came up in the search under this one (which is why I've posted on this one).

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same error and the to fix it is easy you need just to get rid of **whitespaces**  and **apostrophies** your code will be somethiing like this :

```html
{% include "entry_table/cell.html" with_data_items=unicorn class="entry_table_title" only%}
```

and it will fix your code